# Как получить определенное число из Map

Tags: javascript, node.js, функции

Мой код:

```js
const boxes = new Map([
      [60, 'undefined'],
      [61, 'C'],
      [80, 'U'],
      [90, 'R'],
      [97, 'E'],
      [99, 'L'],
    ]);
    const chanche = (Math.random() * 100).toFixed(
      0
    );
    return boxes.get(
      Array.from(boxes.keys()).reduce((a, b) => {
        return a < chanche < b ? a : b;
      })
    );
```

Нужно:
Если

```js
chanche < 60 - undefined
chanche < 80 - C
chanche < 90 - U
chanche < 97 - R
chanche < 99 - E
chanche < 100 - L
```

Возможно ли это реализовать без switch и else if?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Map не нужен.

```js
function gen() {
  return "CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCUUUUUUUUUURRRRRRREEL"[Math.random() * 100 - 60 | 0]
}

function test(n) {
  var count = { undefined:0, C:0, U:0, R:0, E:0, L:0 }
  
  for (q=0; q<n; ++q) {
    var x = gen()
    count[x] = ~~count[x] + 1
  }
  
  console.log(count)
}

test(1000000)
```